# After using docker-compose down,i lost my data

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

First,i changed pg_hba.conf,changed "host all all all scram-sha-256" to  "host all all all md5". after that,i executed "docker-compose down and docker-compose up -d",but not  executed "docker-compose down -v".
After docker starts successfully,I found that the data is lost.i executed "docker volume ls",the result is empty.what caused this phenomenon？
Could someone possibly give me some pointers?Thank you very much!
This is my docker-compose.yml

```
   db:
image: postgres
container_name: postgres
restart: always
environment:
 POSTGRES_DB: postgres
 POSTGRES_USER: polardb
 POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
ports:
  - 5432:5432
volumes:
  - /opt/deploy/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: You seem to have attached a link to an image file in place of your Compose YAML file.  Can you [edit] the question to replace that link with the actual text of the file?  Have you correctly declared `volumes:` to hold the database data?

Comment: thank u very much.I've already changed it

Answer (score 0):

What was lost was the data of the test server, and the data should not be recovered, but I wanted to understand what caused it, so I found a new server for testing, and found that the data was not lost after the same steps.